# Selenium scripts are failing

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

We have selenium scripts (say around 20 scripts). 
When we run all the 20 scripts some how 3 or 4 scripts going to fail but when I run the same script it is going to pass. I don't understand whether I am doing something wrong or if there is any different approach to run multiple scripts. Please help me

Comment: What issue are you getting? What exceptions are coming in these failed tests?

Comment: What exceptions are coming in these failed tests? and with framework you used to run the 20 cases.?(TestNg/Junit)

Comment: different issues like "ElementNotFoundException","ElementNotClickable" etc..,

Comment: different issues like "ElementNotFoundException","ElementNotClickable" etc..,

Comment: I am using testng frmaework to execute all those 20 test cases

Comment: Could you give us some more information, please? Do the same scripts fail in the same places each time? Do any scripts depend on the outcome of prior scripts? Is the machine that runs the scripts able to receive user input while the scripts run?

Comment: Test cases or independent and it is failing at different positions/places.It is not taking any user input,just reading the values from testng.xml(paramater tag and test case details) file and executing the test cases

Answer (score 1):

We have a bunch of selenium test cases and could observe a similar behavior.
We dug into the issues and figured out two things:

1. Make test cases "orthogonal"

Test cases should not depend on each other. But that also means that every test case is responsible for creating the correct precondition for itself to run.
Don't make any assumptions about the environment, e.g. always create fresh empty database tables before running a test case.

2. AJAX is a bit trickier to test

When You are using jQuery / JavaScript on Your site You have to make sure that the asynchronous code is already executed when you make a check
In Selenium you can either wait directly or wait for a specific elements to appear on the site.
You also can inject script code e.g. focus on other element to ensure that the async action is triggered.

For more specific advice some samples of you testcode is needed.